# Old Code-First model has feilds in database but not in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

As an example, the database has the fields

Id, Name, Gender.

The Model has:

Id and Name.

The database is in use and am wondering how to correct this error.

Comment: Why do you think this is an "error"? It may be an unused column, but that doesn't mean that it was an "error" - it may have been intentional. The answer seems obvious: drop the column, use the column, or if you're unaware of the consequences - leave it alone. Probably should check with the database owner prior to modifying the database table and you should also ensure you have a valid database backup. I did notice an error in your spelling of "fields" in the title

Comment: It's a code first database, somehow there is a column in use in the database that isn't in the model in visual studio, when looking at the class at the model, 'Gender' exists nowhere in the code other than in a migration - it looks like it was added to the migration manually

Answer (score 0):

Drop the Gender column if you are not using that column. But make sure that column is not being used and you have a backup of the database before dropping the column. Here is a SQL script to drop that column from the database:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table_name] DROP COLUMN [Gender]
```

Comment: thank you, I could drop the column, but as it's in use I don't want to.